# Accessing server-side control by its ID property in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, multidimensional-array, runatserver

On my default.aspx page I have a bunch of divs with an ID and runat="server":

```html
<div id="serverOne" runat="server"></div>
<div id="serverTwo" runat="server"></div>
<!--etc...-->
```

In my code behind I've declared a multidimensional array (or grid) with 2 values -- the first being an IP address and the second the server name.

```vb
Dim servers = {{"10.0.0.0", "serverOne"}, {"10.0.0.1", "serverTwo"}}
```

My question is, is there a way where I can target my divs from my code behind using a value from the array?

```vb
For i As Integer = 0 To 1

     'This is what I want it to do:
     servers(i, 1).InnerHtml = "<span>Testing " & servers(i, 1) & "</span>"

Next
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using the `FindControl` method on the page.  However, out of the box `FindControl` looks only at the first level of children, and does not go into the childrens' children.  In order to handle this you need to use a helper method that allows `FindControl` to recursively search through the control hierarchy to find the one you want.  Add this method to your code behind, or some shared class that multiple pages can access:

```
Protected Function FindControlRecursive(control As Control, id As String)

    If (control.ID = id) Then
        Return control
    End If

    For Each ctl In control.Controls

        Dim foundControl = FindControlRecursive(ctl, id)

        If (foundControl IsNot Nothing) Then
            Return foundControl
        End If

    Next

    Return Nothing

End Function
```

Once you have that, it's pretty easy to find your `<div>` just by using the string ID property.

```
For i As Integer = 0 To 1

    Dim div = CType(FindControlRecursive(Me, servers(i, 1)), HtmlGenericControl)
    div.InnerHtml = "<span>Testing " & servers(i, 1) & "</span>"

Next
```

**Reference:** http://forums.asp.net/t/1107107.aspx/1